# E2E Encrypted group calls and messaging (plug'n'play solution)

Tags: windows, chat, encryption

I'm looking for something similar to Skype I guess.

Here are the important main features that I need:

- Easy "plug'n'play"-like solution (like Skype for example)
- Safe end-to-end encryption for calls and messages
- Normal two person calls
- Group calls
- Normal two person messaging
- Group messaging
- At least run on Windows (Linux and Mac OS X support would be great, too)

I read about "Wire", but it's E2E encryption feature is limited to calls, messages are decrypted on their servers.

I also read about OTR, which according to Snowden is safe (for the time being) if implemented correctly. But that on the other hand does only work for messages and not for calls.

And then there is the "MEGA Chat". It's browser-based (from what I've read) and thus it has to rely on Flash, am I correct? And I don't trust Flash. I also don't know if MEGA is using proper end-to-end encryption and in an older article I read it doesn't support group calls/messaging (yet). Not sure if that's implemented now. And browser-based means everything goes through a server (no P2P), right? (That could be a problem when sending large files. Although I don't necessarily need such a feature.)

So yeah, are there any solutions?

Comment: If you're willing to consider Android instead of using a PC, I'd look into Signal.

Comment: That is not what I asked for.